# How can I set maxTextMessageSize for Camel's Jetty instance?

Tags: websocket, jetty, apache-camel

I'm using Apache Camel to pass messages through websockets and we're running into an issue where some of our messages are much larger than the default size of 16384 chars which causes the socket to disconnect. I know there's a setting in Jetty called maxTextMessageSize that should allow us to change this limit - but I'm not having much luck figuring out how to set it for Camel's Jetty instance.

I'm not sure if it matters, but all of our Camel configuration is done in Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current you cannot setup these parameter directly on the camel-websocket endpoint.
I just filled a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7150) for it.

Comment: I just committed a part for the JIRA, please feel free to try it out.